# Why can't I use //-style comments in my C code?

Tags: c

I am using `gcc` (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9) to compile a program that I'm writing, but it seems to vomit whenever it sees a // comment in my code, saying:

```
interface.c :##: error: expected expression before â/â token<
```

Does the `gcc` compile mode I'm using forbid `//` comments?

```
$ gcc -g -ansi -pedantic interface.c structs.h -c -I. -I/home/me/project/h
```

Why?

Comment: It's important to realize that the term "ANSI C" is commonly (and *incorrectly*) used to refer to the language described by the 1989 ANSI C standard. That standard was replaced by the 1990 ISO C standard (which describes the same language), and has since been superseded by the 1999 and 2011 ISO C standards. ANSI officially adopted all three ISO C standards after they were published. So strictly speaking, "ANSI C" refers to ISO C 2011 -- which is more clearly called "ISO C". Older standards can still be relevant, but it's clearer to refer to them by year (C89/C90, C99, C11).

Comment: ANSI C can refer to any US adoption of ISO C... so *ANSI ISO/IEC 9899:2011* is a form of ANSI C... but the usual understanding is ANSI C is *ANSI X3.159-1989* which preceded ISO C

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`//` comments are not allowed in old (pre 99) C versions, use `/**/` (or remove the `-ansi`, that is a synonym for the C89 standard)

Comment: Short, accurate and to the point.  Best answer so far, and likely the best conceivable.

Comment: Without `-ansi`, gcc currently supports C89 with GNU-specific extensions; one of those extensions happens to be `//` comments. With `-std=c99`, it attempts to conform to the 1999 ISO C standard, which requires support for `//` comments.

Answer (score 25):

See [C++ comments](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Comments.html) in GNU compiler documentation.

> In GNU C, you may use C++ style comments, which start with `//` and continue until the end of the line. Many other C implementations allow such comments, and **they are included in the 1999 C standard**. However, C++ style comments are not recognized if you specify an `-std` option specifying a version of ISO C before `C99`, or `-ansi` (equivalent to `-std=c89`).

(Emphasis is mine because some of the posts claim that `//` are not allowed in standard C whereas that is only true for pre-99 standards).

Comment: For some of us, "Standard C" was standardized long before '99.  Always wise to specify exactly which revision of the standard!  :-)

Comment: @Brian: So... what we need is a standard... standard.

Comment: Most users who don't have to worry about cross platform stuff will likely be happier with `-std=gnu99`