# Error (generate_uudmap.o) during Perl 5.26.0 installation

Tags: perl, centos7

I'm trying to install Perl 5.26.0 on a CentOS 7 system where I do not have root access. I installed that version of Perl with no problem on another CentOS 6 system. Here is the configure command I executed:

```
./Configure -des -Dusethreads -Dprefix=$INSTALL_PATH/$SOFTWARE-$VERSION
```

And here is the error I obtain:

```
gcc -c -DPERL_CORE -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -std=c89 -O2 -Wall -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wextra -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings generate_uudmap.c
In file included from /path/to/include/string.h:635:0,
                 from generate_uudmap.c:10:
/path/to/include/bits/string3.h:129:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
 // XXX We have no corresponding builtin yet.
 ^
/path/to/include/bits/string3.h:129:1: error: (this will be reported only once per input file)
make: *** [Makefile:250: generate_uudmap.o] Error 1
```

Comment: *"error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90"* : Try remove the `-std=c89` option (or use `-std=c99` instead). See [gcc options controlling C dialect](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) and [Why can't I use //-style comments in my C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2223541/2173773)

Comment: You can try alter C compiler switches by passing them with the `-A` switch to `Configure`. For example:  `./Configure -des -Accflags=-std=c99 [...]`

Comment: However, when I add the `-Accflags=-std=c99`, it generates the following command: `gcc -c -DPERL_CORE -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -std=c99 -std=c89 -O2 -Wall -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wextra -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings generate_uudmap.c`
So basically `-std=c99` and `-std=c89` and generates the same error msg.

Comment: Okay it works now! :D. After the error thrown by Configure, I went into the `sflags` file and commented line #13: `stdflags=" -std=c89"` Many thanks @Håkon Hægland -much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it works now! :D. After the error thrown by Configure, I went into the `sflags` file and commented line #13: `stdflags=" -std=c89"` I ran `make` again and then `make install`

Answer (score 0):

In Centos 7 Perl version 5.30.2 change to `c99` the line `stdflags=" -std=c89"`
in the cflags file for:

Oldline

```
stdflags=" -std=c89"
```

Newline

```
stdflags=" -std=c99"
```

And make install (no `./Configure -des -Dprefix=...`)